# How to obtain the types in a C++11 parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, typeinfo

I'm not sure that I worded the question in the most effective way, but I'm just now starting to use C++11 and am having trouble applying its new features to the problem at hand. I have the following notional function:

```
template <typename ... Args>
std::vector<std::type_index> foo()
```

I would like `foo()` to return a `vector` that contains a `type_index` value for each of the types in the parameter pack `Args`. For example, `foo<int, vector<int>, double>()` would return a `vector` containing `{ type_index(typeid(int)), type_index(typeid(vector<int>)), type_index(typeid(double)) }`.

Notionally, I would like to iterate over the types in the pack and invoke the above transform on each of them (i.e. given a type `T`, return `type_index(typeid(T))`.
I feel like there should be a clean way to accomplish this, but it's not clear to me how to operate the variadic template machinery to make this work. Is my intuition correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to "iterate" over types in a pack is to use pack expansion to repeat the desired pattern. In this case you'd write something like the following:

```
return { type_index(typeid(Args))... }
```

Comment: Excellent! I didn't realize it would be *that* simple. Thanks!